# Text stored in Rails DB showing funny in emails (both text and HTML)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, encoding, character-encoding

I'm stumped. Let's say the text stored in the database is this:

> none of those had handles... @Bobby isn't that wild...

That is exactly how it's displayed in the console when I run Model.first.property_name. And that is what I want to display in the email.

Now, when I insert it into an email template by doing <%= @instance.property_name %>, my HTML and TEXT emails display this:

> none of those had handles... @Bobby=C2=A0isn't that wild...=
>   =C2=A0

Any idea what's going on here, and what I can do to just display the text the way it should look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unexpected [Unicode non-breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) somewhere. A non-breaking space in UTF-8 consists of the bytes \xC2 and \xA0 in that order. That character (which is two bytes long) will appear as `=C2=A0` in the [MIME quoted-printable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7) representation.

Fix up your spaces in the view (if that's where the stray space is) or properly strip your incoming properties (if that's where the stray space is coming from).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That must be it. I didn't know there was a difference in space types.

Comment: Neither does Ruby half the time. Check the results of `"\xC2\xA0".gsub(/\s/, '')`, `"\xC2\xA0".gsub(/\p{Space}/, '')`, and `"\xC2\xA0".strip` in `irb` for examples.